A recurrence for $f(n) = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2k + 1)^{n}\binom{k - 1/2}{k}}$
For an integer $n \geq 2$ consider the absolutely convergent series:
$$f(n) = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2k + 1)^{n}\binom{k - 1/2}{k}} = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{k!^2}{(2k)!(2k + 1)^{n}}4^k$$
Does there exist a recurrence relation of the form
$$\sum_{j = 0}^{J} a_j(n)f(n+j) =0$$
with polynomial coefficients $a_j(n)$ for some fixed integer $J$? The summands of these series are hypergeometric in both $n$ and $k$ but are not of the form needed to use Zeilberger's method of Creative Telescoping. But still, I wonder if such a recurrence relation exists or at least if all of the values of $f(n)$ are linearly dependent over $\mathbb{Q}$ with some finite set of it's values.
We can express $f(n)$ as a generalized hypergeometric function:
$$f(n)={}_{n+1} F_n\left(\begin{matrix}1 ~~~ 1 ~~~ 1/2 ~~~ \cdots ~~~ 1/2\\3/2 ~~~ \cdots ~~~ 3/2\end{matrix};1\right)$$
with $n-1$ one-halfs in the top row and $n$ three-halfs in the bottom row. So the question is effectively this:

Could the hypergeometric function $f(n)$ be expressed as a combination of f(n+j), $~0< j \leq J,$ for a fixed $J$, with coefficients being functions of $n$?

Also, $f(n)$ is an L-function similar to Diriclet's beta function and in fact
$$f(2) = 2G\\
\beta(2) = G$$
where $G$ is the Catalan's constant. But, while $\beta(n)$ asymptotically approaches one from below, $f(n)$ seems to approach one from above
